# Class named XYZ containing itself as a class member

Tags: java, class, object

I have started learning `java` and made some progress.
However, I don't understand the code below while implementing a linked list

```
Class Node
{
    Node next;
    int i;
}
```

In the code above I created a class named **Node** and created **Node** type of variable. If I print that **next** class' member it will `NULL`.

I don't understand the concept.

If that "next" holds reference of variable "Node" why doesn't it print its address on the screen why it printed `NULL` value?

Comment: Because it only holds a reference after you assigned one to it. Unless you do that, a reference is null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement it something like this:

```
Node node = new Node(); // creating first node 
node.i = 0;
Node node1 = new Node(); // creating second node
node.i = 1;
node.next = node1; // assigning next node to previous node
//Now print here for node one
System.out.println("Next node: "+node.next); // it will print identity hashcode not the address as per default toString implementation.
```

Assignment needs to be do it will not happen by itself. //Thumb Rule